# How do I disable the previous dates in custom calendar Android

Tags: android, android-custom-view, android-calendar

In my application I implemented custom calendar for pick the date. But how do I disable the previous dates on custom calendar? 
xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/lightgray"
    android:minWidth="1500dp"
    android:minHeight="1500dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >



    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/buttonlayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="60sp"
        android:gravity="left|top"
        android:height="60sp"

        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:background="#EEEEEE"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/currentMonth"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="60sp"
            android:layout_weight="0.6"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF" >
        </TextView>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/nextMonth"
            android:layout_width="20sp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginRight="10sp"
            android:src="@drawable/calendar_right_arrow_selector" >
        </ImageView>


    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/selectedDayMonthYear"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/calendar_top_header"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" >
    </Button>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/calendarheader"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/calendar_days" >
        </ImageView>
    </LinearLayout>

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/calendar"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:numColumns="7" >
    </GridView>

</LinearLayout>
```

java:

```
package com.reloadapp.reload.fragments;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.format.DateFormat;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.reloadapp.reload.R;

/**
 * Created by user1 on 5/25/2015.
 */
public class Calendardialog_fragment extends DialogFragment implements OnClickListener{
    private static final String tag = "MyCalendarActivity";
    View lay;
    private TextView currentMonth;
    private Button selectedDayMonthYearButton;

    private ImageView nextMonth;
    private GridView calendarView;
    private GridCellAdapter adapter;
    private Calendar _calendar;
    static String tt;
    String second12=null;
    String journeycal;
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    private int month, year;
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    @SuppressLint({ "NewApi", "NewApi", "NewApi", "NewApi" })
    private final DateFormat dateFormatter = new DateFormat();
    private static final String dateTemplate = "MMMM yyyy";

    public static final String Convert = null;
    public static Calendardialog_fragment newInstance() {
        Calendardialog_fragment f = new Calendardialog_fragment();
        return f;
    }


    public Calendardialog_fragment() {

    }


    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.my_calendar_view, new LinearLayout(getActivity()), false);

        // Build dialog
        Dialog builder = new Dialog(getActivity());
        builder.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        builder.getWindow().setLayout(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        builder.setContentView(view);

        _calendar = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.getDefault());
        month = _calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;

        year = _calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);

        Log.d(tag, "Calendar Instance:= " + "Month: " + month + " " + "Year: "
                + year);

        selectedDayMonthYearButton = (Button) view
                .findViewById(R.id.selectedDayMonthYear);
        selectedDayMonthYearButton.setText("Selected: ");


        currentMonth = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.currentMonth);
        currentMonth.setText(DateFormat.format(dateTemplate,
                _calendar.getTime()));

        nextMonth = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.nextMonth);
        nextMonth.setOnClickListener(this);

        calendarView = (GridView) view.findViewById(R.id.calendar);

        // Initialised
        adapter = new GridCellAdapter(getActivity(),
                R.id.calendar_day_gridcell, month, year);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        calendarView.setAdapter(adapter);
        return builder;
    }
    private void setGridCellAdapterToDate(int month, int year) {
        adapter = new GridCellAdapter(getActivity(),
                R.id.calendar_day_gridcell, month, year);
        _calendar.set(year, month - 1, _calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
        currentMonth.setText(DateFormat.format(dateTemplate,
                _calendar.getTime()));
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        calendarView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        if (v == nextMonth) {
            if (month > 11) {
                month = 1;
                year++;
            } else {
                month++;
            }
            Log.d(tag, "Setting Next Month in GridCellAdapter: " + "Month: "
                    + month + " Year: " + year);
            setGridCellAdapterToDate(month, year);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Log.d(tag, "Destroying View ...");
        super.onDestroy();
    }
    public class GridCellAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements OnClickListener {
        private static final String tag = "GridCellAdapter";
        private final Context _context;

        private final List<String> list;
        private static final int DAY_OFFSET = 1;
        private final String[] weekdays = new String[] { "Sun", "Mon", "Tue",
                "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat" };
        private final String[] months = { "January", "February", "March",
                "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September",
                "October", "November", "December" };
        private final int[] daysOfMonth = { 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30,
                31, 30, 31 };
        private int daysInMonth;
        private int currentDayOfMonth;
        private int currentWeekDay;
        private Button gridcell;
        private TextView num_events_per_day;
        private final HashMap<String, Integer> eventsPerMonthMap;
        private final SimpleDateFormat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat(
                "dd-MMM-yyyy");

        // Days in Current Month
        public GridCellAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
                               int month, int year) {
            super();
            this._context = context;
            this.list = new ArrayList<String>();
            Log.d(tag, "==> Passed in Date FOR Month: " + month + " "
                    + "Year: " + year);
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();


            setCurrentDayOfMonth(calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
            setCurrentWeekDay(calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK));

            Log.d(tag, "New Calendar:= " + calendar.getTime().toString());
            Log.d(tag, "CurrentDayOfWeek :" + getCurrentWeekDay());
            Log.d(tag, "CurrentDayOfMonth :" + getCurrentDayOfMonth());

            // Print Month
            printMonth(month, year);

            // Find Number of Events
            eventsPerMonthMap = findNumberOfEventsPerMonth(year, month);
        }

        private String getMonthAsString(int i) {
            return months[i];
        }

        private String getWeekDayAsString(int i) {
            return weekdays[i];
        }

        private int getNumberOfDaysOfMonth(int i) {
            return daysOfMonth[i];
        }

        public String getItem(int position) {
            return list.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return list.size();
        }

        /**
         * Prints Month
         *
         * @param mm
         * @param yy
         */
        private void printMonth(int mm, int yy) {
            Log.d(tag, "==> printMonth: mm: " + mm + " " + "yy: " + yy);
            int trailingSpaces = 0;

            int nextMonth = 0;
            int nextYear = 0;

            int currentMonth = mm - 1;
            String currentMonthName = getMonthAsString(currentMonth);
            daysInMonth = getNumberOfDaysOfMonth(currentMonth);

            Log.d(tag, "Current Month: " + " " + currentMonthName + " having "
                    + daysInMonth + " days.");

            GregorianCalendar cal = new GregorianCalendar(yy, currentMonth, 1);

            Log.d(tag, "Gregorian Calendar:= " + cal.getTime().toString());

            if (currentMonth == 11) {

                nextMonth = 0;

                nextYear = yy + 1;

            } else if (currentMonth == 0) {

                nextYear = yy;

                nextMonth = 1;

            } else {

                nextMonth = currentMonth + 1;
                nextYear = yy;

            }

            int currentWeekDay = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) - 1;
            trailingSpaces = currentWeekDay;

            Log.d(tag, "Week Day:" + currentWeekDay + " is "
                    + getWeekDayAsString(currentWeekDay));
            Log.d(tag, "No. Trailing space to Add: " + trailingSpaces);


            if (cal.isLeapYear(cal.get(Calendar.YEAR)))
                if (mm == 2)
                    ++daysInMonth;


            // Trailing Month days
            for (int i = 0; i < trailingSpaces; i++) {


            }

            // Current Month Days
            for (int i = 1; i <= daysInMonth; i++) {
                Log.d(currentMonthName, String.valueOf(i) + " "
                        + getMonthAsString(currentMonth) + " " + yy);
                if (i == getCurrentDayOfMonth()) {
                    list.add(String.valueOf(i) + "-BLUE" + "-"
                            + getMonthAsString(currentMonth) + "-" + yy);
                } else {
                    list.add(String.valueOf(i) + "-WHITE" + "-"
                            + getMonthAsString(currentMonth) + "-" + yy);
                }
            }

            // Leading Month days
            for (int i = 0; i < list.size() % 7; i++) {
                Log.d(tag, "NEXT MONTH:= " + getMonthAsString(nextMonth));
                list.add(String.valueOf(i + 1) + "-GREY" + "-"
                        + getMonthAsString(nextMonth) + "-" + nextYear);
            }
        }

        /**
         * NOTE: YOU NEED TO IMPLEMENT THIS PART Given the YEAR, MONTH, retrieve
         * ALL entries from a SQLite database for that month. Iterate over the
         * List of All entries, and get the dateCreated, which is converted into
         * day.
         *
         * @param year
         * @param month
         * @return
         */
        private HashMap<String, Integer> findNumberOfEventsPerMonth(int year,
                                                                    int month) {
            HashMap<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

            return map;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View row = convertView;
            if (row == null) {
                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) _context
                        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.screen_gridcell, parent, false);
            }

            // Get a reference to the Day gridcell
            gridcell = (Button) row.findViewById(R.id.calendar_day_gridcell);
            gridcell.setOnClickListener(this);




            // ACCOUNT FOR SPACING

            Log.d(tag, "Current Day: " + getCurrentDayOfMonth());
            String[] day_color = list.get(position).split("-");
            String theday = day_color[0];
            String themonth = day_color[2];
            String theyear = day_color[3];
            if ((!eventsPerMonthMap.isEmpty()) && (eventsPerMonthMap != null)) {
                if (eventsPerMonthMap.containsKey(theday)) {
                    num_events_per_day = (TextView) row
                            .findViewById(R.id.num_events_per_day);
                    Integer numEvents = (Integer) eventsPerMonthMap.get(theday);
                    num_events_per_day.setText(numEvents.toString());
                }
            }

            // Set the Day GridCell
            gridcell.setText(theday);
            gridcell.setTag(theday + "-" + themonth + "-" + theyear);
            Log.d(tag, "Setting GridCell " + theday + "-" + themonth + "-"
                    + theyear);

            if (day_color[1].equals("GREY")) {
                gridcell.setTextColor(getResources()
                        .getColor(R.color.lightgray));
            }
            if (day_color[1].equals("WHITE")) {
                gridcell.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(
                        R.color.lightgray02));
            }
            if (day_color[1].equals("BLUE")) {
                gridcell.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.orrange));
            }
            return row;
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String date_month_year = (String) view.getTag();
            selectedDayMonthYearButton.setText("Selected: " + date_month_year);
            Log.e("Selected date", date_month_year);
            try {
                Date parsedDate = dateFormatter.parse(date_month_year);
                StringTokenizer tokens = new StringTokenizer(parsedDate.toString(), " ");
                String first = tokens.nextToken();// this will contain "Fruit"
                String second = tokens.nextToken();
                String three = tokens.nextToken();
                StringTokenizer split= new StringTokenizer(date_month_year,"-");
                String first1 = split.nextToken();
                String second1 =split.nextToken();

                String three1 = split.nextToken();
                String date= three1 + "-" + second1 +"-" + first1;
                SimpleDateFormat df2 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MMMM-dd");
                SimpleDateFormat df3 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
                Date eDDte;
                eDDte = df2.parse(date);
                journeycal=df3.format(eDDte);
                Log.v("TAG_journeycal",""+journeycal);
                Log.v("TAG", "" + parsedDate.toString());
                Log.v("TAG", "" + first);
                Log.v("TAG", "" +  second);
                Log.v("TAG", "" + three);
                Intent intent1 = new Intent();
                intent1.putExtra("week", "" + first);
                intent1.putExtra("month", "" + second);
                intent1.putExtra("date", ""+three);
                intent1.putExtra("JOURNEY", ""+journeycal);
                getTargetFragment().onActivityResult(getTargetRequestCode(), Activity.RESULT_OK, intent1);
                dismiss();

                //Log.v("TAG",""+web[+ position]);
                /*bundle.putString("name", web[+ position]);
                i.putExtra("a", bundle);
              */
               /* setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent1);
                finish();*/



            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }


        public int getCurrentDayOfMonth() {
            return currentDayOfMonth;
        }

        private void setCurrentDayOfMonth(int currentDayOfMonth) {
            this.currentDayOfMonth = currentDayOfMonth;
        }

        public void setCurrentWeekDay(int currentWeekDay) {
            this.currentWeekDay = currentWeekDay;
        }

        public int getCurrentWeekDay() {
            return currentWeekDay;
        }
    }
}
```

user not able to pick the previous dates from calendar so i need to disable the previous dates from calendar.

Comment: Can you show us your code ?? Do you mean Datepicker ?? You can use [public void setMinDate (long minDate)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/DatePicker.html#setMinDate%28long%29)